# Alter table in impala : make a column a primary key

Tags: sql, bigdata, impala, alter-table, hue

Using Hue, how can I alter a table to make a prexisting column a primary key?

I check and things like :

`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT colname PRIMARY KEY (cs_id);`

is not syntactically correct.

NB: data is stored using Kudu file system.

Answer (score 2):

First, Impala [does not support](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_alter_table.html) `alter contraint` as an option in `alter table`.

Second, [primary keys are very limited](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_kudu.html#kudu_primary_key_attribute):

> The primary key columns must be the first ones specified in the CREATE TABLE statement.

I don't think you can change the primary key after it has been defined.  In Impala, the data is clustered (i.e. sorted) by the primary key, so any change would be quite expensive.

You probably need to recreate the table and reload it with data.

Answer (score 1):

When you are storing as Kudu, you need to consider that the PK columns need to be all created at the creation of the table.
Impala does not support altering primary keys.
I'm afraid you need to delete and create the table again.